# Table data not accepting "overflow" style property

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

Please see the [example](http://jsbin.com/ulubop/1/edit).
I provided `height:150px; overflow:auto;` to all `<td>` tags. On less content the height is working fine. For more content vertical scroll bar need to come. But it is not working here for the table cell.

If I use `<div>` inside the `<td>` tag with the style property `height:inherit; overflow:auto;` means scroll is working.

Any solution or reason is there for the overflowed `<td>` tag?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi now if you change your `td display properties` than **it's work**

as like this

```
td{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: is there any possible to center vertically for the minimum content column data(first column).

Answer (score 1):

Can be solved by specifying `display: block;` and `float: left;` to your TD's style

```
td { height:150px; overflow:auto; display: block; float: left; }
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ofufuf/1/edit

Comment: No scroll bar found for second column of the table.

Comment: Its working. Thanks. But better answer getting by applying `display:inline-block;` only. No need float.

Comment: Yes, using `inline-block` is a better and cleaner way. :)

Answer (score 0):

Table  tag does not support overflow property directly.

You have to do this the way you were trying i.e you have to insert a div inside a td and then add overflow in that div.

`<table>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <div style="height:100px;overflow:auto;">abc</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>`